# Facing Issue When I build the MixedRealityToolkit-Unity (V2) sample project

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2017, hololens, mrtk

I am facing issue when I build the MixedRealityToolkit-Unity(V2) sample project,I faced the following error :

Assets\MixedRealityToolkit.Providers\WindowsMixedReality\WindowsMixedRealityArticulatedHand.cs(418,73): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HandJointKind' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Assets\MixedRealityToolkit.Providers\WindowsMixedReality\WindowsMixedRealityArticulatedHand.cs(111,17): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HandMeshObserver' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Assets\MixedRealityToolkit.Providers\WindowsMixedReality\WindowsMixedRealityArticulatedHand.cs(382,33): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HandJointKind' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Assets\MixedRealityToolkit.Providers\WindowsMixedReality\WindowsMixedRealityArticulatedHand.cs(412,26): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'JointPose' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I am running on Windows 10 Insider preview with
OS build : 18362.30
Version : 1903

Also I double checked with build setting 
Minimum SDK is 10.0.10240.0
Target SDK version is “Latest installed”

I am using mrtk_development branch for the MixedRealityToolkit-Unity.

Can any one help me or guide me if I am missing any steps here for the set-up.

Thanks.

Comment: These errors look like Unity is actually not using the latest installed SDK. Have you tried the following:

(0) Close Unity
(1) Delete your old Build/UWP folder.
(2) Delete Unity's Library folder (yourProject/Library)
(3) Re-open Unity, and build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I am able to build MRTK-V2 into HoloLens :-) Just give it a try by adding [Windows SDK 18362+](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsinsiderpreviewSDK) which is mention on Toolkit home page. 
I thought I am running under insider build 18362.30 so I don't need to install this SDK, But seem like it is required anyway.

Answer (score 1):

These errors look like Unity is actually not using the latest installed SDK. Have you tried the following:

1. Restart your computer (not kidding).
2. Delete your old Build/UWP folder.
3. Delete Unity's Library folder (under YourProject/Library).
4. Re-open Unity, and try to build again.

Comment: Yes, I tried the steps as you suggested above but still I am facing the same issue unity is showing same errors. :-(

Comment: Can you verify that the Windows SDK version that you are using is 18362.30? Maybe you have the insider preview OS, but are not using the actua 18362.30 SDK.